# Real and complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

for what value of x, the Eigenvalues of given matrix 'A' are real?
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
10&5+i&4\\
x&20&2\\
4&2&-10
\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
After writing an expression for characteristic equation i have equate both real and imaginary part of the equation zero ,after which i am getting a biquadratic in both x and 'lambda'.  But 'lambda' can have only three possible values, please help.

Comment: This will help you to show what you want https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple ways to answer this question. One way to look at it very simply is to look at the condition for what makes $A$ a Hermitian matrix, i.e., $A = A^{\dagger}$. Under this condition, we have:

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 10 & 5+i & 4 \\
 x & 20 & 2 \\
 4 & 2 & -10 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 10 & x^* & 4 \\
 5-i & 20 & 2 \\
 4 & 2 & -10 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comparing the two, we see that $x = 5 - i$.

Indeed, if $x = 5-i$, then the characteristic polynomial is: $-\lambda ^3+20 \lambda ^2+146 \lambda -2020$, which has all real roots.

Note that separately I am not claiming that real eigenvalues imply a Hermitian matrix, but your question was not specific to the type of matrix under consideration, so I believe this approach will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of approaching this question without going through the characteristic polynomial. The easiest is to remember that the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix are real.

Another would be to remember that Det($A$) is the product of the eigenvalues so you could start by computing the determinant using $x=a+ib$ and get a condition on $a$ and $b$ to make the determinant real.  However, this path goes not produce a unique $a+ib$ but instead a family of matrices $A$ with real determinants depending on $a$, with only one of them having real eigenvalues, i.e. some effort is required beyond the condition of real determinant, although the characteristic equation contains an imaginary term which can be set to $0$ by a suitable choice of $a$; this choice of $a$ produces real roots.